# How to Centralise SimplePager within a Grid or FlowPanel (or any panels) in UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I tried all ways to centralise a SimplePager in a FlowPanel, then in Grid, in HTMLPanel, DockLayoutPanel, & in `<table>`, but none of them works, ex:

```
<g:FlowPanel>
 <g:Grid addStyleNames="style.alignCenter">
   <g:row >
     <g:customCell >
       <c:SimplePager ui:field="mySimplePager" location="CENTER" />     
     </g:customCell>

   </g:row>

 </g:Grid>
</g:FlowPanel>
```

in Css

```
.alignCenter{ text-align:center;}
```

I did try to centralise SimplePager in FlowPanel using code, then it works. Ex:

```
 FlowPanel myFP=new FlowPanel();
 myFP.getElement().getStyle().setTextAlignment(TextAlign.CENTER);
 myFP.add(mySimplePager);
```

so, How to Centralise SimplePager within a Grid or FlowPanel (or any panels) in UiBinder?

Answer (score 0):

In custom cell can you try with this?

```
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align='center'>
                        <c:SimplePager ui:field='mySimplePager' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Or simpler replacing a flowpanel with an htmlpanel:

```
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align='center'>
                        <c:SimplePager ui:field='mySimplePager' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
```

Comment: have u tried to put your <g:HTMLPanel> inside a DockLayoutPanel? if HTMLPanel not inside DockLayoutPanel then your code is ok, but if it is then somehow it doesn't work

Comment: Often I use the datagrid panel and his pages inside a docklayout panel like this:
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX'>
                <g:center>
                        <c:DataGrid ui:field='dataGrid' />
                </g:center>
                 <g:south size="40">
                        <g:HTMLPanel>
                                <c:SimplePager/>
                        </g:HTMLPanel>
                </g:south>
        </g:DockLayoutPanel>